# bootstrap - set input control(s) size inside input-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a requirement where the input group contains two text-boxes separated by input-group-addon. The problem I am facing is I am not able to set the width of the text-boxes using bootstrap css. The first text-box should be wider than the second text-box.

**JSFiddle:**  https://jsfiddle.net/Vimalan/5eqdkveb/3/

**Current:**

The textbox before and after delimiter are of same size.

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

The textbox after delimiter should be small. I am more interested in a solution which uses bootstrap css and not custom css.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Approval Number</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="ApprovalNumberTextBox" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">Delimiter</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="ApprovalNumberDelimiterTextBox" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you are not able to set text-boxes width?!
You can simply add css rule to the input you want and set its width, like

```
<style>
    #ApprovalNumberDelimiterTextBox {
      width:40%;
    }
</style>
```

and it is working  [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zj8pymfm/) or there is another problem I don't get?

Comment: I am sorry, I should have been more specific. I am looking for a solution without custom css. I just updated the expectation section.